# maven: resolving cyclic dependency

Tags: maven, cycle

My java root project has source code and maven modules it depends on. One of these modules A has a cyclic dependency with the root project. What would be a recommended way to get rid of this cyclic dependency?

UPD: I have solved it already before posting a question, but decided to share.

Comment: anwser: To resolve it, the best way is to extract the code module A depends on from the topmost project to  its own maven module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your root project should have POM packaging and shouldn't contain any code. Move any such code to a new project and configure dependencies to/from this project.

Comment: that's right! Eventually it should happen, now I have just started "modularizing" the project, which is being updated by other developers. So I take one step at a time.